# TestNG Results not displaying in Maven project for Selenium

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

Following are the code and pom.xml which I'm using

```
package com.org.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HelloWorld {

    @Test
    public void Hello() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Logging into account");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Study materials\\Setups\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.close();
    }       
}
```

And pom.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myTestProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>myTestProject</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

On running the project as Maven Test, I get a BUILD SUCCESS, but no result of the actual test is being displayed. Here is the result :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.org.test:myTestProject >---------------------
[INFO] Building myTestProject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ myTestProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Eclipse\myTestProject\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ myTestProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ myTestProject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Eclipse\myTestProject\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myTestProject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ myTestProject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.984 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-30T21:33:57+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried similar threads on Google,and tried updating my dependencies too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rename the class to include the word 'Test' to be picked up automatically by surefire. Refer this https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Renamed class to TestHelloWorld. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Please post this as an answer so that I can upvote it as an answer for future reference to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the class to include the word **'Test'** to be picked up automatically by surefire plugin. Refer this https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html for more details.